# RSelenium Connecting to a running server

Tags: r, selenium

I am trying to use `Rselenium` to automate some of my more tedious reporting tasks

I have downloaded the Java virtual machine as per the [instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#introduction)
I have gotten it running by using the code below

```
 # Run the Command at the command line
 cd selenium
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

In R i then add the following code

```
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                  , port = 4445L
                  , browserName = "firefox"
)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)

remDr$open()
```

When i run the last line i get the error

> [1] "Connecting to remote server"
>   Error in checkError(res) : 
>     Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4445/wd/hub.
>     Please ensure a Selenium server is running.

I can see in the command line window that the server is running as i am getting the message `Selenium Server is up and Running`
Can anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly?

#### Update

I have tried switching the port to 4444 as based on the advice below but i get the error

From the Cmd Prompt

> Selenium message:The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

From R

> Error:     Summary: UnknownError
>        Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>        class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>        Further Details: run errorDetails method

Comment: Isn't the default port for selenium server `4444`?

Comment: I updated my call to the server with this after downloading and installing Gecko: `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/selenium/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`. However when i try to connect on port 4444 i get the error `connection refused: connect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Firefox version 48 the gecko driver is also required to drive a Firefox browser with Selenium Server. The geckodriver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. If you wish to run the Selenium server manually you should then either

- Add the geckodriver path to PATH
- Or set the webdriver.gecko.driver system property on the JVM

The second method would be done as:

`java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="path-to-geckodriver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`

If you are running windows and have downloaded the Selenium standalone to `C:\Selenium` and the geckodriver to the same location then this would look like:

```
C:\Users\john>cd C:\Selenium

C:\Selenium>java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

**NOTE: on a 32bit windows machine you will need the 32bit geckodriver and on a 64bit machine the corresponding 64bit geckodriver.**

Alternatively the recommended way to run a Selenium server with RSelenium is to run a Docker container which includes the Selenium Server, geckodriver and appropriate Firefox browser:

`docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4444:4444 --link http-server selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:3.0.1-barium`

see the vignette at http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: Hi @jdHarrison. My previous comment, i tried this and although it removed my original error it seems to still refuse the connection. `Caused by: og.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2
4096 [localhost/127.0.0.i. localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:i] failed: Connection iefused: connect` Do you know of anyway to trouble shoot it?

Comment: Seems to throw the same error but if i scroll up along the error message i get the first problem here: `C:\selenium\geckodiuer.exe [OPTIONS]
C:\selenium\geckodiuer.exe: Unknown option ——port6949
Attempting bi—dialect session. assuming Postel’s Law holds true on the remote end`

Comment: If a Selenium server is running on localhost port 4444 you should be able to get its status: `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status`

Comment: I ran the command in firefox and got the following `{"state":"success","sessionId":null,"hCode":1112234011,"value":{"build":{"version":"3.0.1","revision":"1969d75","time":"2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700"},"os":{"name":"Windows Server 2008 R2","arch":"amd64","version":"6.1"},"java":{"version":"1.8.0_91"}},"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","status":0}`

Comment: See my edits with regards to windows. This works fine on a Win 10 machine I tried locally.

Comment: Hi @jdharrison. Im still getting problems with the error message being refused. Could it be that i am using a virtual machine in Work to generate it? I dont have rights to execute gecko on my laptop as our group policy is a bit unforgiving

Comment: Is your path to geckodriver correct? You state `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/selenium/geckodriver.exe` this should be `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\selenium\geckodriver.exe"`

Comment: copied it directly `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`. That runs the server without any problems. When i enter the R code in the original question, i get `C:\selenium\geckodiuer.exe [OPTIONS] C:\selenium\geckodiuer.exe: Unknown option ——port6949 Attempting bi—dialect session. assuming Postel’s Law holds true on the remote end` Would the full output be useful? I can put it in the original question?

Comment: I have this issue on a win 7 VM when I run a 64bit geckodriver rather than a 32bit geckodriver. This maybe your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the answer. Its now ticking over nicely. Please submit it as an answer and il mark it. Thanks again for your time