# Batch File Run Java VM

Tags: batch-file

I have a java Virtual Machine i wish to run so that i can web scrape using selenium in R. Please see my thread [RSelenium Connecting to a running server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971090/rselenium-connecting-to-a-running-server/40974146?noredirect=1#comment69163312_40974146) for more details

I want to create a batch file to run it so i dont have to type it each time

Below is my attempt but i keep getting an error saying it cant find the java file

```
chdir /d C:\Selenium\
Start ""  "java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:/Selenium/geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"
```

This is my second attempt at a batch file so it might be a very simplistic question

Thank you for your time

Comment: What java file does it say it can't find?

Comment: Hi, it says it cannot find  `-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`.  I can run the command `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:/Selenium/geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar` from the command line

Comment: Leave out the `start` command. Just put `java -D...` etc. just as you would type it.

Comment: thank you that is the answer :)